# monaco-editor/react addCommand() in ControlledEditor

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

We are using @monaco-editor/react, more specifically:

```
import { ControlledEditor } from "@monaco-editor/react";

...

return (
    <ControlledEditor
                height="85vh"
                editorDidMount={handleEditorDidMount}
                language="xml"
                onChange={listenEditorChanges}
                theme={
                    uiTheme !== undefined && uiTheme === "Default Theme"
                        ? "light"
                        : "vs-dark"
                }
                value={currentTab.choosenFile.value}
                options={{
                    readOnly:
                        (permissions && !permissions.editFiles) ||
                        currentTab.choosenFile.historyFile ||
                        currentTab.choosenFile.used
                            ? true
                            : false,
                    wordWrap: "on",
                    automaticLayout: "on",
                    editorConstructionOptions: {
                        formatOnType: "on"
                    }
                }}
            />
)
```

How do I add a key binding (`addCommand`) to such implementation? I've tried:

```
const handleEditorDidMount = (_: any, editor) => {
        editorRef.current = editor;

        editor.addCommand(17 | 83, () => {
            console.log('save!')
        });
    };
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sky-m6n38?file=/pages/index.tsx) you can try and in the method `handleEditorDidMount` you will have access to `editor` and `monaco` to implement. your addCommand method

Answer (score 0):

I simply used this vanilla Javascript function:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey))      {
        e.preventDefault();
        //your implementation or function calls
      }
    }, false);
```